# What are the general guidelines to configure IMU sensor parameters?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, imu, gyro, magnetometer

Im working on developing a Attitude and heading reference system (AHRS) for my quadcopter project.

Im working with AltIMU-10 v5, it is 10 DOF (gyroscope,Accelerometer,Compass,Altimeter) IMU board.

The gyro,accelerometer and magnetometer, have some common parameters, that are user-configurable. These include : Bandwidth of LPF, sensitivity of each sensor, output data rates(ODR), cut-off freq. digital LPF & HPF configurations after ADC processing etc etc.

**Question:**

**1)** How do I configure these parameters so that it suits my application best? (i.e quadcopter)

*There might not be a definite answer to my question but general guidelines on how to work around these parameters specific to my application, would help me a great deal.*

**Useful Links:**

[AltIMU-10 v5 homepage](https://www.pololu.com/product/2739)

[Magnetometer Application note](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1090/LIS3MDL-AN4602.pdf)

[Magnetometer Datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1088/LSM6DS33-AN4682.pdf)

[Gyro and Accelerometer Datasheet](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1087/LSM6DS33.pdf)

[Application note for Gyro and Accelerometer](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1087/LSM6DS33.pdf)

Comment: high pass filter the gyros and low pass filter the accelerometers

Comment: @DKNguyen LPF & HPF are available for both sensors. My main issue is, on what basis do I select cut off freq of these filters ? How does it affect my system in the end ? What are the pros and cons that I should be aware of ?

Comment: The fact you are trying to think of things in terms of pros and cons makes me think you do not actually know the role of each sensor.

Comment: @DKNguyen I have a basic understanding. The thing im trying to determine is that how does user configurable settings,lets say gyro at 50hz sample rate, will determine performance in terms of accuracy, reliability & response time of overall system. ?

Comment: That is based in a lot of control theory and a mathematical model of the mechanical system. You usually end up in something called a "state space". Unless you are a controls engineer you are perhaps better off tinkering with the numbers by feel and mechanical intuition. Like grabbing your IMU and moving it around at various speeds under different settings while having the output graphed in real-time and judging by eye whether it looks like it actually matches what you did with your hand or not. or not accurate enough.

Comment: @DKNguyen Im not a controls engineer but I do have basic control theory concepts since im a EE student. Can you provide some reference material(books or application notes etc) that can help me steer in right direction according to my question ? Tinkering with numbers sounds more reasonable since I dont have much time at hand but I would like to develop more technical understanding as much as I can.

Comment: Kalman filters are all the rage with IMUs but complimentary filters are easier to implement. So I would start there.